# Compare portal contents in Filemaker Pro

Tags: filemaker

The situation:  I have two tables in a database.  One table resembles a list of students and the classes they are taking (plus other data about that student).  So the table might contain five records for Joe in math, in English, etc., for each name-class combination.  The second table resembles a list of teachers and - in this world - the exactly two classes that each teacher teaches.

I have two portals, one each to show all the names of the students in each class for that particular teacher record.

The task:  I need to find cases where one student is in both classes taught by one teacher.  That is, they appear in the list of students in both portals.

Is there a way to compare the contents of two portals or otherwise identify the students taking two classes from the same teacher?  The portals are nice for displaying the lists but I don't have to anchor a solution to them.  Maybe there's a way to set up the relationships to find those students?  I'd prefer to avoid a script solution but certainly that's OK if there isn't a more elegant approach.

FM Pro 18 Advanced, macOS 13.2.1

Comment: You left out the most important part: how are the two tables related, and what are the portals based on (relationship only, or are they filtered). --- In general, I would expect to see a more complex structure, with tables for Teachers, Classes, Students and Enrollments (a join table between Students and Classes).

Comment: I was vague.  Each portal is based on relating the course code field in the teacher table - each teacher has two classes, two codes - to the course field in the student table.  Each portal then shows all the students listed in that class. The table structure was defined by my "client".   If there's a way to change them that gets the job done, I'm all ears.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not clear. Do you have 2 separate fields for class code in your Teachers table?

Comment: Yes.  Three fields total in that table.  Many fields in the student table but the relevant two are the class field and their name.

Comment: It is.  Is there a way to mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to establish a common vocabulary, consider the following structure:

[image]

Now, assuming there are 2 portals on the layout of `Teachers`, one to each occurrence of the `Enrollments` table, and each containing the `Student` field from the corresponding occurrence:

You can apply conditional formatting to the `Enrollments::Student` field using the following formula:

```
not IsEmpty ( FilterValues ( Self ; List ( Enrollments 2::Student ) ) )
```

and (if you want) apply conditional formatting to the `Enrollments 2::Student` field using:

```
not IsEmpty ( FilterValues ( Self ; List ( Enrollments::Student ) ) )
```

With this arrangement in place, any student that appears in both portals will be highlighted.

---

Note that this structure has some serious flaws - most notably:

- a teacher cannot teach more than two courses;
- in order to change a student's name, you need to change it in all their enrollments, thus exposing yourself to *update anomaly*. In a relational database, names (and any other meaningful data) should be stored only once.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Flaws understood.  This project involves a one-time transfer of data from ancient (FoxPro) database files into a modern one (Salesforce).   Along with that comes the inevitable clean up of obsolete or improperly entered data. I'm not concerned about the final database structure.

Comment: I just need a couple more steps.  I need to not merely identify the students taking both classes, I need to export a flat file listing those students for each teacher.  Like an Excel file with X multiple rows for each teacher if that teacher has X students taking both their classes. Messy, but a means to an end.

Comment: I've figured out how to filter the first portal list to show only the students that also appear in the other portal.  So now I just need to figure out how to export that filtered list.

Comment: The best way would probably be to call the `Go to Related Record` script step while the filtered portal is active. This will create a found set of the records shown in the filtered portal in a layout of the Enrollments table, which you can then export.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up with.

Taking the excellent cue from @michael.hor257k, I set one class's student list portal to "filter portal records" based on whether the student appears in the other class's portal.  The portals are in the Teachers file which shows the two classes taught by each teacher.  The portals list the students who, from the data in the Enrollments table, are in each class. I filtered the first list to show only students that are in both classes, in both portals.

```
FilterValues (  Class1::Student ; List ( Class2::Student ))
```

This script in the Teachers file then does the work:

```
Set Variable [ $file; Value:Get(DocumentsPath) & "StudentList.csv" ]  //  Output file
Get File Exists [ “$file” ; Target: $fileExists ]
If [ not $fileExists ]
    Create Data File [ “$file” ; Create folders: Off ]
End If
Open Data File [ “$file” ; Target: $fileID ]

Show All Records
Go to Record/Request/Page [ First ]
Loop
    Go to Field [ Teachers::Key ]
    [ Select/perform ]
    Set Variable [ $stringEnd; Value:Teachers::Key & ", "&Teachers::Class1& ", "&Teachers::Class2 ]
  Loop
     Go to Portal Row [ Select; Next; Exit after last ]
     Set Variable [ $student; Value:Portal1::Student ]
     Set Variable [ $string; Value:$student&", " & $stringEnd ]
     Write to Data File [ File ID: $fileID ; Data source: $string ; Write as: UTF-16 ; Append line feed: On ]
  End Loop
Go to Record/Request/Page [ Next; Exit after last ]
End Loop

Close Data File [ File ID: $fileID ]
```

The result is a .csv file with a list of all students that are taking two classes from any teacher.  It's long and has lots of replicated data but apparently this format is what the client needs to move forward.

Comment: I thought you wanted a separate file for each teacher. It turns out your final goal is very different from your original question.